# How to distinguish between compactification and closure

Tags: general-topology

I know that if $Y$ is compact Hausdorff, $Y=\overline{X}$, then it's a compactification of $X$. So a compactification is a form of closure. Are there more subtle relations between the two?

Comment: For Hausdorff spaces every compact set is closed but the reverse in not true in general. That a compact set in a Hausdorff space is closed is a consequence of the definition of compactness, that is, for each open cover of a compact set exists a finite subcover. Sorry if it sounds rude but your question is similar to this other question "how one can differentiate oranges than lemons if both are citrics?"

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that compactification involves the *creation of an entirely new space* while closure happens *within an existing space*. Compactification is something that happens to topological spaces. Closure is something that happens to subspaces.

More precisely, compactification of a topological space $Y$ is *creation of a new space* $X$ such that $Y$ embeds in $X$ and $X$ is compact.

Closure of a subspace $Y$ of $X$ is the *identification of a new subspace of $X$*, call it $\bar{Y}$, such that $\bar{Y}$ is a closed set with $Y\subset \bar{Y}\subset X$ and any closed $A\supset Y$ has $A\supset \bar{Y}$.

Comment: This distinction is spurious. A compactification contains a subspace homeomorphic to the original space whose closure is the compactification. The closure of any subspace of a compact space is a compactification of the subspace.

Comment: The closure need not be compact, consider the closure of $(0,\infty) \subset \mathbb R$, but the one-point compactification of $(0,\infty)$ is $S^1$ (not realizable inside $\mathbb R$).